# Chrome 47 bug in flexbox, scrollbar overlap

Tags: css, google-chrome, scrollbar, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to display two columns:

- container flex-direction: row
- overflow-y: auto

When content changes in the left column, the right column shifts left to overlap the scrollbar and part of the left column.

http://jsfiddle.net/zshbLsev/

Not seeing this with any other browser, I assume it's a bug, but any ideas on how to fix without throwing out the flexbox-direction: row would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"  onclick="revealtext()">
        click me    
        <div id="display-text" style="display:none">
            left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left left 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        middle
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    height: 200px;
    width: 600px;
}

.left {
    background: darkgray;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 200px;
    border-right: 5px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

.middle {
    background: gray;
    flex: 0 0 400px;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border-left: 5px solid green;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

**JS**

```
revealtext = function() {
    var el = document.getElementById('display-text');
    if (el.style.display == 'block')
        el.style.display = 'none';
    else 
        el.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Comment: It's a bug in chrome 47, but it's already fixed in 48 and later.

Comment: Is it? If I fire up `browserstack` with chrome 48 (`48.0.2552.0 dev-m` by the time of writing), the error still exists. On the other hand chromium 49 (`49.0.2589.0 (64-bit)`) doesn't seem to be affected...

Comment: Someone over at chromium bugs said it was fixed in 48, but I only tested it in 49 myself