# Chrome incorrectly rendering scrollbar in Flexbox layout with overflow: auto

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox

With following CSS/HTML:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: 200px;
}
.left {
  flex: 0 1 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: red;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='left'>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>left</p>
    <p>end</p>
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    right
  </div>
</div>
```

I expected to see scrollbar on left panel, as in IE & FF:

[image: IE]

But on Chrome `Version 47.0.2526.106 m` there is about **50% chance** I got:

[image: chrome]

The problem may appear/disappear by changing browser windows size and/or reloading page. Using Chrome dev tool, I found right panel is shifted left by about 15px causing it to overlap on the scrollbar of left panel.

Is this a bug in Chrome? How to get expected output in Chrome without setting overflow to scroll?

Same code in https://jsfiddle.net/a9o5h00y/

Comment: Seems to be ok for me

Comment: @cameronjonesweb, The problem may appear/disappear by changing browser windows size. Also, I use Windows 7, not sure if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ok yep getting on browser resize.

Comment: Running into the same thing -- glad I'm not the only one.  At first I thought my left div scrollbar was disappearing, but in fact the right div was just overlapping by the exact width of the scrollbar....

Answer (score 2):

Tested in Chrome (Version 47.0.2526.80 m), Firefox and IE11.

Scroll bar appears in all browsers without issue.

However, as noted, the scroll bar disappears in Chrome on window re-size.

First note about this: If you refresh the page, the scroll bar re-appears.

Second note: Due to the arbitrary disappearing act, I think it's safe to classify this as a bug.

---

***Cross-Browser Solution:***

Based on:

> *Using Chrome dev tool, I found right panel is shifted left by about 15px causing it to overlap on the scrollbar of left panel.*

I found that the following code patches the "bug" on all browsers listed above:

```
.left {
    flex: 0 1 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative; /* new */
    z-index: 1;  /* new */
}
```

[**Revised Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/a9o5h00y/1/)

In fact, based on the [CSS layout stacking order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32515284/3597276), `z-index` shouldn't even be necessary in this case. The patch should work with `position: relative` alone.

---

But again, it does appear to be a bug in Chrome 47, which has been resolved in subsequent versions:

- [Chrome 47 bug in flexbox, scrollbar overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34214716/3597276)

Comment: Thanks @Michael_B. I also came up with the z-index idea. I consider it as a mitigation rather than complete solution because it essentially hides the left 15px portion of the right panel. An ideal solution should shift right panel to right by 15px.

Comment: I posted a link that may shed some light. Looks like the bug is resolved in Chrome versions > 47.